# url index of 1 and 10 and 11 the same

Tags: jquery

How can i fix this issue i'm having , indexing url to add css.

When i go to url index of #10 or #11 , it is applying the css to url index of #1 , how can i match #1 verse #10 and #11 ?

```
if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#1') > -1 ) {
  $('#tabcontent1').css('display','block');
}
if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#10') > -1 ) {
  $('#tabcontent10').css('display','block');
}
if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#11') > -1 ) {
  $('#tabcontent11').css('display','block');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.location.hash`

```
var curr = document.location.hash.slice(1);
$("#tabcontent" + curr).css("display", "block")
```